# acyclic implies identity null-homotopic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I have proved the following for a chain complex $\mathcal{C}_{*}$ where the $\mathcal{C}_i$ are free $\mathbb{Z}$ modules, $\mathcal{C}_i = 0$ for $i>0$.

The identity map on $\mathcal{C}_{*}$ is null-homotopic if and only if $(\mathcal{C}_{*}, \delta_{*})$ is exact and acyclic.

I know that if we drop the condition that $(\mathcal{C}_{*}, \delta_{*})$ is split, we still have that: $id$ on $\mathcal{C}_{*}$ is null-homotopic $\Rightarrow$ $(\mathcal{C}_{*}, \delta_{*})$ is acyclic.

I am unsure, however, whether or not the other direction is true. That is, if $(\mathcal{C}_{*}, \delta_{*})$ is acyclic, is the identity map null-homotopic?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the case of the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2} \rightarrow 0$ seen as an exact complex. Is it contractible, ie. is the identity null-homotopic?

Comment: @PiotrPstragowski I see that this particular sequence is not contractible, and so the statement does not hold in this case. But, for my problem, I am working with free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: Ah! I figured it out. It is true when we take $\mathcal{C}_{*}$ as a chain complex of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. In particular, I think this statement holds generally if the free modules are defined over PIDs.

Comment: Well, if you are still here, you can check Weibel, Exercise 1.4.1 that acyclic bounded below chain complexes of free (in fact, projective) $R$-modules are always split exact, and an acyclic chain complex of free abelian groups (in fact, modules over PID) is always split exact.